# How do you prove $n! \leq (n/2) ^n$?

Tags: induction

I'd be really grateful if someone could help me figure out how you prove   $n!\leq (n/2) ^n$ ?

Comment: Not true for $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=3$, $n=4$, $n=5$. Do you mean $(\frac{n+1}2)^n$?

Comment: Nope, I rechecked the question, it's (n/2) ^n

Answer (score 6):

$$\sqrt[n]{n!}=\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots n}\le \frac{1+2+3+\cdots+n}{n}$$
(using the [arithmetic-geometric mean inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means))

Now $1+2+3+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ ([why](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)), so the RHS becomes $\frac{n+1}{2}$.  Raise each side to the power $n$ and you get $n!\le (\frac{n+1}{2})^n$, as @Hagen suggests.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a more accurate estimation, you can approximate $\log n!$ by an integral:
$$ \log n! = \log 1 + \dots + \log n \leq \int_{1}^{n+1} \log x \ dx = [x \log x - x ]_{1}^{n+1} \\ = (n+1) \left(\log(\frac{n+1}{e})\right) - 1.$$
It follows that:
$$ n! \leq \frac{1}{e} \left(\frac{n+1}{e}\right)^{n+1}.$$
Because $e > 2$, this implies that $n! < (n/2)^n$, if $n$ is reasonably large.